# I get raw html views with no bootstrap styling in codeigniter version 3.1.1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I tried doing the following:

`$autoad['helper']=array('url');`

My views linkhref:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css">`

I added the assets folder in the project's root [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbNUK.jpg)

My controller looks like this

```
//Home Actions controller
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();  
  $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index($page='home')
{

    if(!file_exists('application/views/templates/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        show_404();

    }
    $this->load->view('templates/'.$page);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try checking the source code of the page that is supposed to be bootstrap-styled:

- Right Click + View Page Source
- F12

Go to your `<head></head>` section and check the url generated by your code `<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css`

Now, you can try to access the generated URI, and consider ajusting it to get the correct path to your resource `bootstrap.css`!

---

This is the 'hard' but efficient way to troubleshoot issues with accessing assets!

PS: Don't forget to Shift + F5 to force reloading cache (for Google Chrom at least)

Hoping it will help you!

Comment: I get no definitions found

Comment: Hmm... what is the exact string you get? Have you try accessing the generated link?

Comment: This is the generated [ link] (href=localhost/CodeIgniter//assets/css/bootstrap.css), I get 404 Error when I click on it. @Antoine Facq

Comment: You should now try to find the path to the correct resource... you should be able to access bootstrap.css from your browser. Check the path and see what's wrong. What if you put the file in another place ? Could you access it from your browser ?

Comment: Hi,I finally managed to get it to work.I realised I did not set the $config['base_URL'], turns out it automatically assign a base_url for you, which could lead to discrepancies. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `application/config/config.php` file with a text editor and set your base URL.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_configuration.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I finally managed to get it, the problem was I did not setup the base_url which is what lead to the problem.